# Hibernate save and update

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

When using hibernate, I have two classes, say

```
    Class Message{
         private String message;
         private User fromhow;
         getter and setter....
    }

    Class User{
         private String userName;
         private String password;
         private ArrayList<Message> messages;
         public User(){
             this.messages = new ArrayList<>();
         }
         // getter and setter.....
      }
```

The question is: when I login as an exist user, I want to save some message created by this user. Do I just need to write like:

```
   Message m = new Message();
   // set Some Attribute of m.
   user.getmessages().add(m);
   session.update(user);
```

or do I also need to save `m` in message table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to save m in message table

Comment: session.update(m);
you need get id of m ,find m from table by id,
user.getmessages().add(m);
session.update(user);